# How to correctly bind `<esc>` in zle vi visual mode in zsh 5.0.8

Tags: zsh, zsh-zle

The standard behaviour of `<ESC>` zle vi-mode when in visual mode is to do nothing. But I want that the action of pressing `<esc>` in vi-mode visual mode switches the keymap to vi-normal mode (`vicmd`). As it does in standard vi.

I tried this:

`bindkey -M visual '\e' vi-cmd-mode`

but it did not work.

[This](https://github.com/ninrod/nin-vi-mode/blob/master/nin-vi-mode.plugin.zsh) is the vi-mode configuration file that I'm using

how can I achieve the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- in *zsh* 5.0.8:

  ```
  nin-deactivate-region() {
     REGION_ACTIVE=0
  }
  zle -N nin-deactivate-region
  bindkey -M visual '\e' nin-deactivate-region
  ```
- from *zsh* 5.1 you already have a `deactivate-region` widget so it would be easier:

  ```
  bindkey -M visual '\e' deactivate-region
  ```

Comment: It seems that at least in *zsh* 5.1.1 and 5.2 `deactivate-region` is bound to `^[` (`<ESC>`) by default.

Comment: True. this is only needed in zsh 5.0.8

Comment: Anyway, it's really nice to know that, because I could remap it to `ctrl+c`, as in Vim: `bindkey -M visual '^c' deactivate-region`